# Solving for (x+y) in terms of a, b, c, d

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Equation $1$:
$$(a-x)b = x(x+y)$$

Equation $2$:
$$(c-y)d = y(x+y)$$

where $a, b, c, d$ are constants. Find the value of $(x+y)$ in terms of $a, b, c , d$.

Can someone please help me with this question?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation 1 can be rewritten as
$$
ab=x(x+y+b)\Rightarrow x=\frac{ab}{x+y+b}.
$$
Similarly, Equation 2 can be rewritten as
$$
y=\frac{cd}{x+y+d}.
$$
Summing the LHS and the RHS of these equations we obtain
$$
z = \frac{ab}{z+b}+\frac{cd}{z+d},
$$
where $z = x+y$. Now solve the equation for $z$.